# python subprocess.call not finding specified file from windows task scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a python script that uses `subprocess.call()` to call `openssl`, and it runs fine from command line.
However, when I run through windows task schedule, the job fails with

> > Winrror2 : specified file not found

The same job runs fine from task scheduler when `subprocess.call()` is removed.
I tried replacing `openssl` command with simple `cp` copy but it still shows the same error.

Note:
1. I'm using python v3.6
2. The job is set to run using SYSTEM account with highest privileges.
3. After searching net, I included `shell=True` as well; no luck. The only difference is - it suppressed the error message in log

Here is the part of the code:

```
infilepath  = str(r'C:\Test\filename.txt.bin')
outfilepath = str(r'C:\Test\filename.txt')
deckeyfile = str(r'C:\Test\decryptionkey.key')


#decrypt the file
try:    
    subprocess.call(["openssl", "cms", "-decrypt", "-inform", "DER", "-in", infilepath, "-binary", "-inkey", deckeyfile, "-out", outfilepath], shell=True)
    #subprocess.call(["cp", infilepath, outfilepath])
    decryptcount += 1
except Exception as e:
    module_logger.error("Failed to decrypt with error: %s", str(e), exc_info = True)
    errorcount += 1`
```

Comment: can you try removing shell=True?